# Can I prevent keyup event after a keydown in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyevent

Are keydown-keyup js events linked? Can I control an event during keydown to prevent the next keyup event of the same key?

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
   if(some_condition)
       e.preventDefault(); //I don't want keyup after this
}).keyup(function (e) {
   if(keydown_was_prevent_default) {
       alert("Exit without keyup!");
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Just remove the keyup event?

Comment: I edited my question to better explain, I have to control the same gesture/key, when I push down a button, in some circumstances, I want to prevent the next keyup (of the same key!). This is why I want to know if the two events keyup/down are linked.

Answer (score 3):

They aren't connected.

You could pass state between them using a variable.

```
(function () { // IIFE to avoid making `block_keys` a global

    let block_keys = false;

    $(document).on("keydown", event => {
        if (some_condition()) {
            block_keys = true;
        } else {
            block_keys = false;
        }
    });

    $(document).on("keyup", event => {
        if (block_keys) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

}());
```

If you were to do this on an *element* I would probably use `data()` to store the state so it would be associated with the element directly.

Comment: I want to block the same keyup, not every other keyup.

Comment: @Tobia — And that is what this does. If you set `block_keys` when the key goes down, it is going to be in that state for when the key is released … not when it is released, pressed down again, then released again.

Comment: What happens if i fired these events with this order: keydown(Akey), keydown(Bkey), keyUp(Bkey), keyUp(Akey)? If Akey has "some_condition" it locks also the B-keyup event.

Comment: I explain here with this fiddle why this solution doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/a0ux7dqf/ (the condition used is just an example)

Comment: I have updated the fiddle from @Tobia: https://jsfiddle.net/xnq7Lu8f This version fixes a typo in some_condition that caused an assignment. I have also added a second key code to that condition (for my own reasons) and a console out for 'unblocked' keys

Comment: Added my own answer with a working fiddle based on this answer

Answer (score 1):

## Yes you can

Old question, but the answer is relevant to me right now:

JS *keydown* and *keyup* events are not 'linked' per se. But, you can control an event during keydown to prevent the next keyup event of the same key. To block the actual event, use something like `event.preventDefault()`. Here is example code based on Quentin's answer. I used a map that tracks `block_keys` to fix the issue found by Tobia:

```
(function() { // IIFE to avoid making `block_keys` a global

  let block_keys = {};

  $(document).on("keydown", event => {
    if (
      event.code === "KeyA" ||
      event.code === "Backspace"
    ) {
      block_keys[event.code] = true;
    } /* else {
      block_keys[event.code] = false;
    } */
  });

  $(document).on("keyup", event => {
    if (block_keys[event.code]) {
      block_keys[event.code] = false;
      event.preventDefault();
      $("body").append(event.code + " Prevented<br>");
    } else {
      $("body").append(event.code + " Allowed<br>");
    }
  });

}());
```

JSFiddle based on the one Tobia posted of Quentin's code: https://jsfiddle.net/xnq7Lu8f/2/